# getting EF ToBindingList to filter, join and more linq like stuff

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a telerik rad grid, but I think this applies to others as well.

I have a parent / child relationship. When the user edits something in the child I am needing the parent data to update.  I am updating the database but the grid parent row is not databound realtime.

this is how I am currently doing it and it works except for this last thing:

```
            var stops = (from s in dbContext.stop_details
                     join c in dbContext.customers on s.customer_id equals c.id
                     where (s.ship_date >= startDate && s.ship_date <= endDate) && s.status == 1
                     select new
                     {
                         s.id,
                         s.ship_date,
                         s.stop_id,
                         s.con_name,
                         s.con_address1,
                         s.con_address2,
                         s.con_city,
                         con_zip = s.con_zip.Substring(0, 5),
                         stop_weight = (int)s.stop_weight,
                         s.order_number,
                         s.customer.customer_name,
                         s.con_state,
                         s.lading_qty,
                         s.hazard_qty,
                         s.hazard_weight,
                         s.record_created,
                         s.stop_canceled,
                         s.stop_changed,
                         s.status,
                         s.items_del_ytd,
                         s.wgt_del_ytd,
                         s.note,
                         s.con_contact_email,
                         s.con_contact_name,
                         s.con_contact_phone,
                         s.del_req_date,
                         openQty = s.lading_qty - s.items_del_ytd,
                         openWgt = (int)s.stop_weight - (int)s.wgt_del_ytd
                     }).ToList();

        this.radGridView1.DataSource = stops;

        dbContext.stop_event.Load();

        GridViewRelation relation = new GridViewRelation(this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate);
        relation.ChildTemplate = gridViewTemplate1;
        relation.RelationName = "EventsToStops";
        relation.ParentColumnNames.Add("id");
        relation.ChildColumnNames.Add("stop_id");
        this.radGridView1.Relations.Add(relation);
```

Telerik support suggested doing the following:

```
dbContext.stop_details.Load();
        this.radGridView1.DataSource = this.dbContext.stop_details.Local.ToBindingList();
```

And this does load the data but it loads everything, I added this which provides some filtering:

```
     this.radGridView1.DataSource =
            this.dbContext.stop_details.Local.ToBindingList().Where(ch => ch.customer_id == 2);
```

BUT...
I lose the join data such as s.customer.customer_name
and how do I do the openQty = s.lading_qty - s.items_del_ytd type stuff??

Any help is apprecaited --

Joe

Comment: I'm trying to solve a very similar problem. Have you tried using `.Include()` at all?

Comment: There is some excellent documentation related to your problem on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232

Comment: Dan- I will read through those, Telerik suggested that I pull the full dataset then use the filtering on the grid to accomplish this.  I have worked around it other ways.  I am going to close out the question -- your documentation post is very interesting.